# Using database in python, have to add a new row in the existing table, but get a lot of errors

Tags: python, database

I am a beginner when it comes to code, and I am working on a school assignment where I have to Add a new student, and
ask the user for the following (in order):

Name,
Email and
Year.
Then adds the new student to the database.

My code is as follows:

```
new_student = Students(id=5, name='Lise', email='lise@.com', year=2020)
session.add(new_student)
session.commit()
student = session.query(Students).get(new_student.id)

for students in student:
    print(f'Added student: {students.id} {students.name} {students.email} {students.year}')
```

I got a lot of errors after I wrote this code, and the last line says "*sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: New instance  with identity key (, (5,), None) conflicts with persistent instance* "

What is wrong with my code, and what is missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of Student Class as well?

Comment: @R.yan yes ofc, her is the student class: `Base = declarative_base()

class Students(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'students'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    year = Column(Integer)`